# Nginx to service two React apps

Tags: nginx

I am having trouble to service two react app with nginX. 
However I try to call `mySiteURL/admin` route, it keeps showing `mySiteURL`
Here is my config file.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html/recipetube-client/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /admin {
    root /var/www/html/recipe-tube-admin/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

How can I change my config to be able to serve two react app on one sever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to use these `location {}` blocks:

```
location / {
    alias /var/www/html/recipetube-client/build/;
}
location /admin {
    alias /var/www/html/recipe-tube-admin/build/;
}
```

Note the trailing `/` for the `alias` line

You may read more about the `alias` syntax [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

The docs say you need to add a trailing `/` for admin but in my experience, this requires website visitors to strictly use `mySiteURL/admin/` with the trailing `/`. 
If they try to access `mySiteURL/admin`, they'll get `404 Not Found`.

I took out the `/` in my `location /admin {}` block, and `mySiteURL/admin` worked fine.

In summary:

`location /admin/ {}` -> Access `mySiteURL/admin/` -> OK

`location /admin/ {}` -> Access `mySiteURL/admin` (no `/`) -> 404 Not Found

`location /admin {}` -> Access `mySiteURL/admin` -> OK

`location /admin {}` -> Access `mySiteURL/admin/` -> OK

Hope this helps you!